# Android. Require user to prompt password to mount sdcard

Tags: android, security, operating-system, usb

I need to configure/program my Samsung Galaxy tab so that if anyone plugs a USB cord he will need to input a correct password if he wants to access files (on his computer). If he doesn't have a password he can only charge the device.

I will be lending it to some people (part of a project) and I need to keep some files hidden from them, but said files are needed for my apps to work. Also the files are too big for internal storage, I have to use the SD card.

Edit: Referring to a comment. the tablet will be specially sealed preventing the ejection of the SDCard

Any and all insight appreciated.

Comment: Kinda a useless endevour.  They can simply eject the card and slip it into a card reader.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, but yes, the tablet will be sealed and the SDCard inaccessible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this without modifying the firmware. Encrypt your files for *some* protection. Not 100% because the encryption key needs to be in the app for it to work.

Comment: Nitpick: Modified firmware implies unlocked bootloader, so a malicious user can install his own firmware to access the SDCard.

Comment: If you actually have the manufacturer/bootloader keys, it doesn't have to be unlocked.